# Using Magento 2.3 REST endpoints to get product attributes

Tags: rest, get, magento2

There are two ways (at least) of using the Magento 2.3 REST API to return product attributes for a specific product.  You can use either:

GET /V1/products and pass a search filter specifying the SKU in the request parameters,

or:

GET /V1/products/{sku} with the SKU specified in the URL.

The second method is probably preferable, but can't be used if the SKU contains slashes (as is the case with a significant number of our products). Generally the two methods give identical results (as you would hope!), but I am currently working with a group of disabled (ie status = 2) products, and getting distinctly odd results (at least they appear odd to me).  I can see if I do a direct query on the database that there are over 1000 disabled products.  If I use the second REST method above to get the details of any of those products, that all works fine, and I always get back the details I would expect.  But if I try using the first method, then only about 150 of them return the expected data - the remainder just return an empty items list, as if the product can't be found.

Can anyone explain under what circumstances the two methods above might behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have identified where the problem is, though I need to do some more research to find out exactly what I need to do.  For the REST calls I specify 'scope' in the URL, and in the original database query I specified 'store_id' in the query, and I thought I was comparing like with like.  But looking at the store ids in which the products are defined, I am finding a definite pattern differentiating the products that are visible to the first REST method and the ones that are not.  There is clearly something more I need to understand about how scope is defined and used.